# How do I add different Smart App Banners to various pages on a wordpress site?

Tags: php, ios, wordpress, escaping, double-quotes

My mobile site (wordpress, self-hosted) has multiple pages, each of which should have a unique Smart App Banner to encourage users to download the app relevant to that specific page.

I apologize if I'm missing something simple but I'm quite new to php.

In the header.php file, I've put the following code block before '/head'

```
<?php if ( is_page_template( 'read.php' ) ) 
print ("<meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=574041839"/>"); ?>
```

Unfortunately, I get an error in the first line.
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/content/b/e/r/berrymed/html/wp-content/themes/TheCorporation/header.php on line 32

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the `"` sign inside html code you want to output using `print`. If you don't do that, php will think you want to output `"<meta name="` and then it will get to unexpected string (as quoted in the error) `apple-itunes-app`. Here is how it should look:

```
<?php if ( is_page_template( 'read.php' ) ) 
print ("<meta name=\"apple-itunes-app\" content=\"app-id=574041839\"/>"); ?>
```

---

Alternatively, if you are using double quotes (`"`) in the output string, you can wrap it in single quotes (`'` just like you do with `is_page_template`) so you don't have to escape:

```
<?php if ( is_page_template( 'read.php' ) ) 
print ('<meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=574041839"/>'); ?>
```